# SQL - Group By ID and transform Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like follows:

```
ID  Cat
1   Large
1   Small
1   Medium
2   Small
2   Medium
3   Large
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
ID  Small   Medium   Large
1   Small   Medium   Large
2   Small   Medium   NULL
3   NULL    NULL     Large
```

I have tried a number of different approaches but they don't seem to work

Thanks for your help

Comment: _I have tried a number of different approaches but they don't seem to work_  You should include your attempts in your question.  It could be a minor syntax issue that is preventing you from getting the final result.

Comment: so where does big fit in this?

Comment: Are you wanting the word 'Big' Changed to 'Large' as part of this too?

Comment: @xQbert yeah sorry should be large

Comment: Your update can't be what my answer is producing, since your result isn't grouping by `ID`

Comment: @Lamak you're right, sorry! Got it working now thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird desired output, but alas:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN Cat = 'Small' THEN 'Small' END) Small,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Cat = 'Medium' THEN 'Medium' END) Medium,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Cat = 'Large' THEN 'Large' END) Large
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but this doesn't quite work, I shall update the question and show you what it produces

Comment: @neeko Obviously you are not providing all of the details this does produce what you want -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dd03/1

Comment: @bluefeet Well, op updated his question, but the results don't make sense

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc183/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
PIVOT(MAX(Cat) FOR Cat IN (Small,Medium,Large) ) p
```